# View puts output generated by Rails app running on server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, logging, ruby-on-rails-4, puts

So If I run irb, pry or rake tasks from the Terminal, any `puts` statements are output to the Terminal.

But how do I view this output from a Rails app running on the server (I'm using POW).

I know I can use the logger to output to the log and tail that, but `puts` output doesn't get written to the log and I don't want it there anyway.

**So where do 'puts' statements output to when the code is running on the server and how can I watch this output?**

Answer (score 1):

On OSX, take a look in the

```
~/Library/Logs/Pow/apps/
```

directory, there must be a log file in there, which has the same name as your app-symlink.

Does it work for you?

**UPDATE**

Try to do set the following in your `.powenv` file.

```
export ENABLE_REMOTE_DEBUGGER_UNDER_POW=true
```

Comment: Thanks, but I've looked there. These logs do not contain any puts output. Just server logging, eg. [Fri Jan 31 2014 11:27:37 GMT+0000 (GMT)] DEBUG nack worker exited

Comment: You're right about the POW docs, but I get no puts output in them.

Comment: i've updated my answer, i guess you have to set a flag for that.